# while getting user input within a loop, if input given as float loop stops. what causes this?

Tags: c, loops, variables, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int mynumber;
    while(1){
        scanf("%d",&mynumber);
        if(mynumber>0){
            while(mynumber>0){
                printf("%d ",mynumber--);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If user inputs an `int`, it works as intended. When float is given it prints all numbers but exits loop at the same time.

I want to learn why and how this could happen?

Comment: I recommend you check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*.

Comment: Since `.` is not accepted, `return 0;` is executed in the next loop.

Comment: As for your problem, when `scanf` sees the decimal-point (or comma) in the input, it will stop parsing the input, since that character can't possibly be part of a decimal integer number. *However*, that decimal-point will be left in the input buffer for the next call to `scanf`. Which will see the decimal-point, fail, and leave it in the buffer. And so on and on...

Comment: Using `scanf` for user input is evil. Use `fgets` and do the parsing yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude; Your second comment is the answer I was about to write.

Comment: By the way, if `scanf` fails it will not modify the argument. That means if `scanf` fails, then `mynumber` is still uninitialized and will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value. Another reason to check what `scanf` returns.

Comment: @MichaelWalz; It's evil only when you want string as input.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you. i got it. i think i also check/see/read how scanf works.

edit:  I think comments are not flagged as answer. thank you again.